# Any amount of padding causes a full-size div that is a direct child of the document body to grow in size

Tags: css, padding

I have a div with no content as a lone child of the document body. `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` styles are applied to it. Applying any amount of padding (width or height) to the div causes it to grow in size, past the parent body.

**The HTML Document:**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS applied to the previous HTML Document:**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

Can someone please explain this behavior and how to prevent it? I thought padding would shrink content until there is no space left before expanding width and height, but the div is without content and has ample room for extra padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with the CSS box model, padding, border, and margin do not affect the width or height of an element.

In the below image you can see the box model of the `div` with padding. The width and height (blue box in the middle) are equal to the window width and height, regardless of the padding, which adds an extra 32px on all sides to that, causing overflow. (Image taken from Chrome DevTools)

[image: Box Model diagram showing the div with box-sizing: content-box]

To change this behaviour, you can use the [`box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, the dimensions of the div now take padding into account. The blue box in the middle has been shrunk to fit the padding into the set dimensions.

[image: Box Model diagram showing the div with box-sizing: border-box]

Some people recommend to set this property on every element ([{ box-sizing: border-box } FTW](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/))

Comment: I have been a web dev for maybe a little over two years and always thought the border-box behavior that I expected where width collapses to padding was the default. Maybe its because I've just been developing on top of abstractions for so long

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
*
{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

> The **box-sizing** CSS property sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated.

> **border-box**
>
> > The width and height properties include the content, padding, and border, but do not include the margin. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box. For example, .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} renders a box that is 350px wide, with the area for content being 330px wide. The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.

Normally you can set **box-sizing** to specific elements instead of **"*"**. But in general, People use same **box-sizing** in whole project, or at least same **box-sizing** under same module. thats why I suggested to use **"*"**

You can read details here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: hi, please could you edit your answer to explain in more detail? thank you in advance

Comment: @cornonthecob Updated

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your CSS rule to INCLUDE the padding in the `width`. If not, the padding will be ADDED to the defined width (in your case this will result in a width larger than 100%, and therefore an overflow/scrollbar).